# curl get запрос на node js

Tags: node.js, curl, get

Есть пример запроса такого вида:

curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json' \
-H 'Client-ID: uo6dggojyb8d6soh92zknwmi5ej1q2' \
-X GET 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/44322889/follows/channels/129454141'

Как правильно такой запрос послать через node js и получить ответ?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

Comment: @Alex Sazonov к сожалению я не селен в node js, я находил что то похожее в интернете, но мне не понятно как что и куда из этого запроса подставлять нужно, как я не пытался это сделать у меня не получается составить правильно и все время получаю ошибки. Подскажите пожалуйста на моем примере как это должно выглядеть чтобы я смог понять как это должно быть.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так. Это вариант на чистой ноде. Но можно еще глянуть в сторону [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). Удобная библиотечка. Я чаще её использую. Вариант ниже по доке набросал, не проверял. Скажи как что получится. Не забуть импортировать модуль `http`.

```js
const options = {
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json',
    Client-ID: 'uo6dggojyb8d6soh92zknwmi5ej1q2'
  }
};

http.get('http://nodejs.org/dist/index.json', options, (res) => {
  // тут приходит ответ в res, с ним уже можно работать
  // вот тут нам надо поместить значение level в переменную
  let levelRes = res.level;
  // далее с этой переменной работаем
});
```

Comment: подключил модуль вот так var http = require('http'); верно?

Comment: вместо этого http://nodejs.org/dist/index.json я так понимаю нужно поставить это https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/44322889/follows/channels/129454141 так? Я все это проделал но выходит ошибка: Client-ID: 'uo6dggojyb8d6soh92zknwmi5ej1q2' SyntaxError: Unexpected token '-'. Что не так я сделал?

Comment: Может кто подсказать что не так?

Comment: Люди добрые есть кто сможет помочь мне решить этот вопрос?

Comment: @boogiman70 `'Client-ID'` попробуй в кавычки взять. Я неправильно написал без кавычек

Comment: Да в кавычках была проблема, подскажите вот я получил ответ например такого вида:

Comment: "id": 4055833268,
    "original_id": 2838729037,
    "defindex": 30140,
    "level": 10,
    "quality": 6,

Comment: Как мне получить в переменную значение которое находится в "level"?

Comment: @boogiman70 подредактировал ответ. Если ответ был полезен, буду благодарен за отметку этого ответа как полезный и рейтингу вверх ;)

Comment: @boogiman70, все заголовки в `headers` нужно обнернуть в `""`, например: `'Client-ID': 'uo6dggojyb8d6soh92zknwmi5ej1q2'`. если не заработало, отпишите